# Delete entire Row with zeroes apply to all worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have VBA code that works to delete entire row when there is an absolute zero value in one a cell column but, I am not able to figure out how to update code to apply to all worksheets (there are 20 Sheets in my workbook):

Can someone help with syntax how to update this code to apply to all worksheets in the workbook.

```
Sub IfandthenDelete_Button3_Click()

Dim lRow As Long

Dim i As Long

lRow = 3000

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For i = lRow To 1 Step -1

   If Cells(i, 1) = 0 Then

   Rows(i).Delete
        End If

Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

Comment: 1. You are not re-enabling screen updating; merely repeating the `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` command. 2. Is your data structured such that an autofilter command could speed things up?

Comment: Thank you!!...Yes.  I  re-enabled screen updating with True and I was not properly adding second loop to search all worksheets cells which I was looking to do.  This is working now very helpful to understand what was needed.

Comment: on the autofilter..I was thinking if that was used will it slow the calculation down?....or speed things up?  Basically, there are zeroes in column "A" in that have zeroes i want to delete entire row.

Comment: Bulk operations are almost always faster than looping through rows or columns and examining each individually. It will ultimately be faster with AutoFilter but still time consuming to delete large numbers of discontiguous rows in large (>10K rows) data blocks. The fastest would be to sort all zeroes to teh bottom of the data block and delete them as a contiguous set of rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need one more `for` loop for that.

```
Sub WorksheetLoop()
    Dim wsCount As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    lRow = 3000
    wsCount = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

    For j = 1 To wsCount

        For i = lRow To 1 Step -1
            If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(j).Cells(i, 1) = 0 Then
                ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(j).Rows(i).Delete
            End If
        Next

    Next j

End Sub
```